# Convert 19 digits Timestamp into readable milliseconds format

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have timestamps like this 1.581580e+18. I tried the following

```
df['timestamp'] =pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

i got the output as 2020-02-13 07:46:40. But i want also the milliseconds to be displayed here

Comment: In my tests, the number in scientific connotation needs at least 10 decimal places to be able to save the millisecond information. You can test too using the number `1.5815800004e+18`

Comment: But if you want to show milliseconds with zeros, you can use the following command: `df['timestamp'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")`

Comment: yes. Thanks!! you are right.